# Find the missing properties of cyclic number

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Guess a 6 digits number in the form of $\ abcdef$ which holds Properties #1, #2 and #3. The real challenge is to find 4 other interesting properties of this number:

---

- Property #1

$\ a+d=b+e=c+f=9 $

$\ ab+cd+ef=99 $

$\ abc+def=999 $

$\ abcd+efab+cdef=9999 $

---

- Property #2

$\ abcdef^2= ghijklmnopq$

$\ ghijk+lmnopq=abcdef$

---

- Property #3

$\ def^2 - abc^2=fabcde $

$\ efa^2 - bcd^2=abcdef $

$\ fab^2 - cde^2=bcdefa$

---

- Property #4 (found!)

> $\ 1\times abcdef=abcdef$
>
> $\ 2\times abcdef=cdefab$
>
> $\ 3\times abcdef=bcdefa$
>
> $\ 4\times abcdef=efabcd$
>
> $\ 5\times abcdef=fabcde$
>
> $\ 6\times abcdef=defabc$

---

- Property #5

  > hint: Improve the equation below to gain cyclic number similar to previous properties (p is a prime number):

> $\ \frac1p =0.\overline{abcdef}$
>   ...

---

- Property #6

> hint: following formula can be starting point for reproducing cyclic number( r and s are two constant numbers that you need to find):
>
> $\ r^1\mod\ s=c $
>
> ...

---

- Property #7

> hint: following formula can be starting point for reproducing cyclic number(p is a prime number):
>
> $\ 10=3+(p \times a) $
>
> ...

---

Note: What I mean by $ abc $ is concatenation of numbers or mathematicaly speaking, $ abc $ is $ (100*a)+(10*b)+c $.

Spoiler:

> Prime number which produce this cyclic number is p=7

Comment: feel free to edit the question so that it become more clear and understandable. tnx

Comment: Wow. An idea jumped out right away, but it only fit the first two properties. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Share your idea :-) interesting to know

Comment: 333333. Worked great initially. Question, though...When you're stating those properties, are we taking things like abc + def = 999 to be the concatenation of a, b and c or is it the product of the digits? Makes a HUGE difference.

Comment: Concatenation. So basically what I mean by $ abc $ is $ (100*a)+(10*b)+c $

Comment: I update the question with found property. still 3 other missing

Comment: There needs to be some hint for the properties. If not, they could be anything and I'm going to close as too broad.

Comment: I updated question with hints

Answer (score 15):

Given that $abc+def=999$, we must have $a+d=b+e=c+f=9$ because there's no way to produce a carry anywhere. From property 3, we must have $d>a$, $e>b$, $f>c$, otherwise the numbers on the right would be negative. $$fabcde=def^2-abc^2=(def+abc)(def-abc)=999(def-abc)=999(def+def-999)=999(200d+20e+2f-999)$$ But $$fabcde=1000(fab)+cde=1000(fab)+(999-fab)=999(fab+1)=999(100f+10a+b+1)=999(100f-10d-e+100)$$ So $200d+20e+2f-999=100f-10d-e+100$, which we can rearrange to get $30d+3e=157+14f$. $157+14f$ must be divisible by 3, while $f$ must be at least 5 and at most 9. The only possibility is that $f=7$. Then $abcdef=142857$.

Some other properties of the number $142857$:

- $2\times142857=285714$, which is the same number but shifted over. The same thing happens for 3, 4, 5, or 6 times.
- $7\times142857=999999$.
- If you multiply $142857$ by *any positive integer*, add the last six digits to the rest, and continue until you have only six digits, the result will be $999999$ or a cyclic shift of $142857$. This results from a combination of the previous two properties.
- $0.\overline{142857}=\frac{1}{7}$, which is part of the explanation for why all of these properties hold.

Comment: Brute force reveals this to be the only solution to satisfy Properties 1–3. Awesome work with the other properties!

Comment: didnt think about simple $ a+d=b+e=c+f=9 $, interesting ! I added it to question

Comment: you discovered one of properties: the shifting numbers when multiply it by 1 to 6. about 1/7, you are very near to discover another one. hint: try to make it shifting somehow ;-)